# How do I get my artboard to appear behind the grid?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm new to Illustrator. I've just started a new project and my artboard is appearing in front of the grid, per below.

[image]

How do I force my artboard to appear behind the grid, so I can use it for my work? Also, I tried adjusting the grid dimension, but it appears it is pre-set to points. Can I just change the dimension to px and it will conform to pixels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Grid preferences, uncheck ***Grids in Back***

[image: Illustrator Preferences]

However, I don't think it's your **Artboard** that is in front of the grid, that looks like a ***Shape*** (I can see an anchor, artboards don't have anchors). Your artboards should appear behind the grid regardless of this option.

Yes, you can change the dimension to pixels and it will convert it to pixels for you (this works just about anywhere in Illustrator). The "Gridline every" setting will reflect what you currently have your ruler set to. To change your ruler units, look under the ***Units*** preferences:

[image: Units preferences]

Alternatively you can just right click on the ruler so long as you have them enabled.

Comment: I would agree.. it's not the artboard in front but an object in front of the grid. You **can't** move the artboard in front of the grid, ever.

Answer (score 4):

You want your grid in front, not back. Check this preference panel.

[image]